# conflict versions android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I have the following issue and can not build my app

Found play-services:12.0.1, but version 11.4.2 is needed for the google-services plugin.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':lib_baselibs:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.

these are the versions that I am using

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
ext.support_version = '27.1.1'
ext.google_version = '12.0.1'
ext.firebase_version = '12.0.1'
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: yes I have tried to use 11.4.2 and it does not work

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail try to avoid specific version and keep up with the latest version try my answer and tell us what happend

Comment: I know this might be silly, but if the app stopped building all of the sudden, can you try to invalidate AS's cache, clean then rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Avoid same version number and update to the latest version, use google play services:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

And update firebase based on [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) to the latest version like below (pick what you need):

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

And also make sure that you are using latest version of com.google.android.gms:play-services like (example) based on [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
```

Comment: @Amira Elsayed Ismail is this help you?